# Simple creation of a new element in XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, element

I know it's supposed to be simple, but it's not working out for me.
I need to translate XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
    <element name="Name1" value="Text1"/>
    <element name="Name2" value="Text2"/>
    <element name="Name3" value="Text3"/>

</items>
```

to XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<goods>
    <!-- some text -->
    <Name1>Text1</Name1>
    <Name2>Text2</Name1>
    <Name3>Text3</Name1>    
</goods>
```

I create XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="goods">
            <xsl:comment>
                some text               
            </xsl:comment>      
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/items/element">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>     
            </xsl:element>                  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it's wrong. Can I put template on other template? Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the child nodes e.g. change

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="goods">
        <xsl:comment>
            some text               
        </xsl:comment>      
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="goods">
        <xsl:comment>
            some text               
        </xsl:comment>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>    
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

or, of course, as you don't need to compute the `goods` element name, better and easier use a literal result element

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <goods>
        <xsl:comment>
            some text               
        </xsl:comment>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>    
    </goods>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Both options helped, but according to the conditions of the problem, this solution is the surest!

Answer (score 0):

You could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/items"> 
    <goods> 
        <xsl:comment>some text</xsl:comment> 
        <xsl:for-each select="element">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>     
            </xsl:element>                  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </goods> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this can only work if the names in `@name` are valid XML element names.